# wpf theme changed my aligmnent

Tags: wpf, alignment, themes

I applied BureauBlue.xaml theme to my application and it wreck my all alignment. Is there any solution to apply theme without destroying my alignment???

Place your theme in "Themes" Folder.

```
application
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
 Application.Resources>

  ResourceDictionary>
   ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/BureauBlue.xaml"/>
   /ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  /ResourceDictionary>
 /Application.Resources>
/Application>
```

I just removed starting bracket of my code because it does not shows my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to App.xaml and paste there lines there and you will be using Vista Theme very near to Windows7, for progress bar, checkboxes, menu, ration buttons, scroll bar and etc but you will NOT having glass look.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=3.0.0.0,
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
    ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```